# Scala collections: Why is Elem contravariant in Builder but covariant in TraversableLike?

Tags: scala, collections, covariance, contravariance

Covariance is very intuitive to me, but my understanding of contra-variance is a little shaky.  I understand the contra-variance in `Function[-A, +B]` because an `Animal => Int` function can be used wherever a `Rabbit => Int` function is used.  I don't really understand how this same sort of contra-variant relationship applies to `Builder`'s `Elem` term, and in particular, why `Builder`'s `Elem` is contra-variant but `TraversableLike`'s `Elem` is covariant.

Comment: (I'm trying to read through this guide: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/architecture-of-scala-collections.html)

Comment: __contra-variant__ = "in" = only used as method argument. Builder: you can only add elements, never retrieve them. __co-variant__ = "out" = only used as method return value. Immutable collection: you can only retrieve elements, never add them (without creating a new collection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a rule of thumb:

> contra-variance is for function parameters and variance is for function return type

I am going to elaborate this. Generally if you have a function like:

```
def f(a: A): B
```

you can pass any instances of all **sub-type of A** to this function and assign the result to a value which is type of any **super-type of B**

So imagine you have the following generic type:

trait Builder[Elem, To]

This means that you can add elements which are type of `Elem` to form an instance of type `To`. For example having the following types:

```
class Animal
class Cat extends Animal
class Dog extends Animal
class Tiger extends Cat

val a: Builder[Cat, ArrayBuffer[Cat]]
```

gives you a builder to build `ArrayBuffer` containing elements of type `Cat`. What we want is a more general constructs. Let's take a look at the following example:

```
implicit val builder: Builder[Cat, ArrayBuffer[Cat]] = ...
def build(elements: Tiger*)(implicit b: Builder[Tiger, ArrayBuffer[Animal]]): ArrayBuffer[Animal] = { ... }
```

We have a build function which needs an implicit in the scope with which it could make an `ArrayBuffer[Animal]` out of array of `Tiger`instances. Let's back to some logic.

- It is logical to assign `ArrayBuffer[Cat]` to a value with type `ArrayBuffer[Animal]`.
- It is logical to add a `Tiger` to a `ArrayBuffer[Cat]` because Tiger is kind of cat.

So our `build` function logically should be able to use `builder` implicit val to form ArrayBuffer[Cat] or more generally to form ArrayBufer[Animal] out of given collection of `Tiger` instances. This only possible if the following relation is held:

```
Builder[Cat, ArrayBuffer[Cat]] <: Builder[Tiger, ArrayBuffer[Animal]]
```

In this case `builder` can be picked as `b` parameter upon invocation of `build` function.

The only way to make this relation happen is to change Builder trait to following:

```
trait Builder[-Elem, +To]
```

So since `Tiger <: Cat` and `Cat <: Animal`, according to contra-variance on `Elem` and variance on `To`, `Builder[Cat, ArrayBuffer[Cat]] <: Builder[Tiger, ArrayBuffer[Animal]]`.

Back to the introductory rule of thumb: you want to use elements of type `Elem` to form a collection of type `To`. imagine it as a function where `Elem` is the parameter type and `To` is the return type. So contra-variance on the parameter type and variance on return type, make it a logically correct generic function.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with builder, as the doc says:

> The base trait of all builders. A builder lets one construct a collection incrementally, by adding elements to the builder with += and then converting to the required collection type with result.

Let's assume we have a function which takes Builder as a parameter.

```
def addCatAndBuild(builder : Builder[Cat, Buffer]) = {
    builder += new Cat()
    builder.result()
}
```

The only builders we are able to use here are those, which have supertype of Cat specified as their Elem parameter (you can add Cat to any Animal collection). Builder[Animal, Buffer] can be used here, but not Builder[ThreeLeggedCat, Buffer] (because not every cat has only three legs).

As for TraversableLike - this trait has no methods with Elem (or A, as in scaladoc) instance paramter. There are methods accepting Elem => Whatever functions. Some methods return other collections of Elem, (eg. List[Elem]), and all of those collections have covariant type parameters.

In terms of TraversableLike's operations, anything you do on TraversableLike[Animal, Repr] can be also done on TraversableLike[Cat, Repr].

```
def allCanWalk(tl : TraversableLike[Animal, Repr]) =
   tl.forall(_.canWalk)
```

To sum it up, it's the interface of class and it's usage of type paramters that allows them to be covariant or contravariant.